# pip install selenium syntax error

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I want to scrape content from a website, but I get the following error already when trying to install selenium, thoughts?

```
/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py:220: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2174, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1907, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 220
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction) currently Selenium is supported by Python 2.7, 3.5 versions and above. If you use Python 2.5 you won't be able to use Selenium.

You can download latest Python version from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and re-try installation